# How to visualize the covariant derivative $\nabla_XX$?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, general-relativity

I was wondering if someone could explain how one could visualize the covariant derivative, in particular, the covariant derivative of a vector field along itself ($\nabla_XX$).

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/62602/272127

Comment: One simple description is that is that $\nabla_XX$ measures the degree to which the integral curves of $X$ deviate from geodesics.